# Rearrange \n separated dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape, display

I have a dataframe object that I am trying to display correctly in python. Actually, I successfully extracted a table from a docx file, but unfortunately, that table is not displaying correctly. I have tried the following code but without success:

```
# Split the column values into rows and reshape the dataframe
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split('\n')
df = df.explode(df.columns[0]).reset_index(drop=True)

# Display the dataframe
df
```

I get a messy table in which all the rows are put in one column and the values of these rows per year are mixed too. I have attached the csv file of the generated table and also a picture of how the table should look like.

CSV file link: [CSV file](https://github.com/LeGentilHomme/Bilan-Project/blob/main/output2.csv)
Picture: [Picture link](https://github.com/LeGentilHomme/Bilan-Project/blob/main/Picture%20of%20the%20table.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "display correctly ": what is correctly here? Please clarify what your expected output is, or what is wrong in the current output and how you want to have that changed.

Comment: Sorry, that hpicture is unreadable. Usually, when displayiing a dataframe, you end up with text (or rendered html). Typing just `df` in Python will not even display your dataframe, so what are you using to run the code, and how is it actually displayed?

Comment: The purpose of the csv file was to just show the output. Here is an clarification about my issue:

Code used to extract the table from the docx file: [link](https://github.com/LeGentilHomme/Bilan-Project/blob/main/Code.txt) 



Docx file: [link](https://github.com/LeGentilHomme/Bilan-Project/blob/main/Bilans%20et%20comptes%20de%20r%C3%A9sultat%20des%20Banques%20et%20%C3%A9tablissements%20financiers%20de%20l'UMOA%20-%202002.docx)



output: [link](https://github.com/LeGentilHomme/Bilan-Project/blob/main/Screenshot_python.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output is not fully clear but here is a good start :

```
import docx
​
fn = "Bilans et comptes de résultat des Banques "\
     "et établissements financiers de l'UMOA - 2002.docx"
​
dx = docx.Document(fn)
​
data = [[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in dx.tables[2].rows] #`[2]`/3rd table
​
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]).set_index("")
        .rename_axis(index=None)#.replace("\s+", "", regex=True)
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                                     2000                    2001       2002
ACTIF                                      Millions de francs CFA           
CAISSE                             81 240                 123 643    136 619
CREANCES INTERBANCAIRES           703 517                 838 476  1 149 153
...                                   ...                     ...        ...
Reçus d'établissements de crédit  262 730                 237 018    294 206
Reçus de la clientèle             622 524               1 067 186  1 227 070
ENGAGEMENTS SUR TITRES              1 621                   4 799      4 447

[70 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Using your code, I get the same messy table. For the first tables of the docx file, everything works fine. But when I tried to display the table with index 17 with this code, it does not work:

`import docx

fn = "/content/Bilans et comptes de résultat des Banques et établissements financiers de l'UMOA - 2002.docx"

dx = docx.Document(fn)

data = [[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in dx.tables[17].rows] #`[2]`/3rd table

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]).set_index(df.columns[0])
        .rename_axis(index=None)#.replace("\s+", "", regex=True)
)`

Comment: That's obvious because your question concerns the third table and not all the tables found in the `.docx.` file. The code should be re-adapted for each **kind/format** of those tables.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought that my code in the txt file stated the exact table index.

Comment: I tried to modify your code accordingly without success. The code doesn't work as the table 17 has all the rows in one column. Like you mentioned, the code needs to be adapted to each table but how? I have tried all the  combinations but can't figure out how to deal with this specific table.  Here is the new code I have tried but still without success: [link](https://github.com/LeGentilHomme/Bilan-Project/blob/main/New%20Code.txt)